# Dúvida programa que copia de um arquivo para outro em C com funções

Tags: c, funções, arquivo

Tenho que fazer um trabalho em C que faz a cópia de um arquivo para outro em tempo de lançamento (no linux usando o argc e argv). Não sou muito acostumado com manipulação de arquivos, mas aqui está o código e não está funcionando, o que posso fazer pra dar certo? Fiz essas 3 funções que pede:

- função que verifica se os argumentos passados para o programa estão corretos. Essa função retorna 0 se os argumentos estiverem corretos, caso contrário deve retornar um valor > 0, um valor para cada possível erro;
- função que imprime mensagens de erro conforme um código de erro passado para essa função;
- função que copia um arquivo para o arquivo destino.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>​
#define MAX 1000 // Atribuição para leitor char.​
#define MEN 500 // Atribuição para leitor char na função copiar arquivo​
​
void CopiaArq(FILE *arq1,FILE *arq2) // Função que cópia um arquivo e cola no outro.(2)​
int Arg(int n, char *v);// Função que retorna valoros maiores que 0 , quando há algum erro no programa.(1)​
char MensErro (char[MEN]);// Função que envia mnsagens de erro.(3)​
​
int​
main(int argc,char *argv)​
{​
    FILE *p==argv[2];// Nome do arquivo destino com atrubuição de valor no argv[2].​
    FILE *b==argv[4];// Nome do arquivo destino com atrubuição de valor no argv[4].​
​
    if(argc<5 || argc >5)​
    {​
        fprintf(stderr,"Erro de digitação no terminal\n");​
        return 1;​
    }​
    else​
    {​
​
    p=fopen("argv[2]","r"); // Abrindo arquivo no modo de leitura , somente para ver o seu conteúdo.​
    if(p==NULL)​
    {​
        fprintf(stderr,"Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");​
        return 2;​
    }​
    b=fopen("argv[4]","w");// Abrindo o arquivo no modo escritra , possibilitando a copia dos arquivos.​
    if(b==NULL)​
    {​
        fprintf(stderr,"Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");​
        return 3;​
    }​
    int Arg(argc, *argv); // Chamada da função(1).​
    char MensErro (char[500]); // Chamada da função(3).​
    void CopiaArq(p,b); // Chamada da função(2).​
    fclose(p); // Fechamento do arquivo p.​
    fclose(b);// Fechamento do arquivo b.​
    }​
  return 0;​
}​
​
void CopiaArq(FILE *arq1,FILE *arq2) // Função que coopia arquivos.​
{​
    char leitor[MAX];​
        while(fgets(leitor,MAX,arq1)!=NULL)​
        {​
            fputs(leitor,arq2);​
        }​
}​
​
​
int Arg(int n, char *v[])// funçãp que retorna valores maiores do que  zero se forem falsas e retorna 0 se for verdadeira.​
{​
    int n;​
    int i;​
    char v[4];​
​
    if(n!=5)​
    {​
        fprintf(stderr,"Erro de passagem nos argumentos para o terminal\n");​
        return 4;​
    }​
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)​
    {​
        fscanf(stdin,"%s",v[i]);​
        if (v[i]!=4)​
        {​
            fprintf(stderr,"Erro de passagem nos argumentos para o terminal\n");​
            return 5;​
        }​
        else​
        {​
            return 0;​
        }​
    }​
}​
char MensErro (char[MEN])// Função que mprime mensagem de erro.​
{​
    int i;​
    for(i=0;i<MEN;i++)​
    {​
        fprintf(stderr,"Codigo passado errado");​
    }​
    return MensErro;​
}​
​
```

Comment: Por que não está funcionando? Dá mensagem de erro, ou a saída não é a esperada? Já utilizaste um debugador para saber onde pode estar ocorrendo o erro?

Comment: Acabei ficando sem tempo e vou ter que enviar o código como está, mas de qualquer forma vou tentar usar o debugger depois, ás vezes tem uma chance de correção. Muito obrigado!

Comment: FILE *p==argv[2]; aqui você está fazendo uma comparação? não seria uma atribuição? (usando = em vez de ==)